# React-360 Oculus Quest won't go into VR Mode

Tags: oculus, react-360, quest, webxr

I have to be missing something:
I installed node.js, installed react-360, created the Hello360 app but can't get the page to go into VR Mode in my Oculus Quest via the Oculus Browser. It just looks the same as it does on a PC.

After googling for a while found a note that said it only works with https so I got that working and ... nope no VR.

Under Windows 10 Professional.

Answer (score 2):

React 360 uses the WebVR API. Oculus Browser removed support for WebVR in version 9. This is why it's not entering VR.

The replacement for WebVR is WebXR. You might want to pick up a different library which supports WebXR, like [AFrame.](https://aframe.io/)

[immersiveweb.dev](https://immersiveweb.dev/) has some links to other frameworks (yes, including React 360, but that link is a 404 :P). Or you could go bare-handed with the WebXR API directly.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Doesn't Facebook manage both the React360 and Oculus Browser API's? Why would they make them incompatible with each other?

Comment: As you can see, React 360 is archived and has not been updated in over a year: https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-360

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the live React-based project right now is https://github.com/pmndrs/react-xr based on https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber